# How do I receive appended data using dropzone using PHP

Tags: php, dropzone.js, dropzone

I am trying to use dropzone to upload an image, and pass the folder to upload the image to.

My html form:

```
<form action="upload.php" class="dropzone" id="dropzoneFrom"></form>
<br>
<div align="center">
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info" id="submit-all">Upload</button>
```

My JS Script:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
Dropzone.options.dropzoneFrom = {
    autoProcessQueue: false,
    acceptedFiles:".png,.jpg,.gif,.bmp,.jpeg",
    
    // Initiate the button
    init: function(){
        var submitButton = document.querySelector('#submit-all');
        myDropzone = this;
        submitButton.addEventListener("click", function(){
            myDropzone.on("sending", function(file, xhr, formData) {
               formData.append("folder", "04"); // Append the folder to upload to.
            });
            myDropzone.processQueue();
        });
        this.on("complete", function(){
            if(this.getQueuedFiles().length == 0 && this.getUploadingFiles().length == 0)
        {
         var _this = this;
         _this.removeAllFiles();
        }
        });
    },
```

};

I am appending the additional folder to upload to like this:

```
myDropzone.on("sending", function(file, xhr, formData) {
               formData.append("folder", "04"); // Append the folder to upload to.
            });
```

But in my upload.php page, how do I receive this information? I am currently receive the file and processing it like this:

```
if(!empty($_FILES)){
$temp_file = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
$location = $folder_name . $_FILES['file']['name'];
move_uploaded_file($temp_file, $location);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found this page which gives a really good modelled example showing that you simply use the $_POST['folder'] request:

https://gist.github.com/kreativan/83febc214d923eea34cc6f557e89f26c

Comment: Please don't post link-only answers but summarize the linked content or its relevant parts a little. A link may become invalid or outdated and in that case, your answer would be useless in the future.